# Cant't find a path for the image React styled components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, path

**I cant't find a path for the image React styled components. The path is correct I think, could it be the styled-components issue ?
https://codesandbox.io/s/soirees-ll0ehp?file=/src/App.js:120-698**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export default function App() {
  const Main = styled.div`
    height: 100vh;
    background: center / cover no-repeat url("./assets/main.jpg");
    background-color: grey;
    background-image: url("../src/assets/main.jpg");
  `;
  const FindPicsWrapper = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 60vh;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  `;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Main>
        <Header />
        <FindPicsWrapper>
          <FindPics />
        </FindPicsWrapper>
      </Main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use:

```
import img from './assets/main.jpg';
```

then use it as:

```
url(${img})
```

[image: Edit Soirees (forked)]